# Featured Images in WP not showing

Tags: php, wordpress

Added the line of code in my function.php file

`add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');`

After going saving, and looking at my screen options, Featured images still wasn't showing. I even went as far back to check if my Custom Fields was correct and I had it unmarked to show

Comment: **screen options?** are you talking about admin section or front end section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out the answer just last night. In the CPT UI on the left hand side there is a settings area "Click headings to reveal available options.", click on the settings caret and at the bottom under supports select Featured Images. And then of course going into your function.php and adding

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails' );

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hi #EliCollins Use this code. It should work

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
function theme_setup() {
   add_theme_support('post-thumbnails' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: (I assume it's a typo in your description): Change `function.php`to `functions.php`

Second: Try to call `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails')` within a function attached to the `after_setup_theme` hook as shown in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support).

```
// Register Theme Features
function custom_theme_features()  {

    // Add theme support for Featured Images
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}

// Hook into the 'after_setup_theme' action
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_features' );
```

I hope these steps will fix your issue, otherwise it would be necessary to provide more of your code